# Getting a new usb wifi dongle working, old one still works?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I am trying to get a BrosTrend ac1200 working on 20.04. Have currently been using TPlink AC1300 T4UH. The old one still works. I have had to install and re-install the drivers for the TPLink a number of times so I thought I understood the steps but now the new one only shows on lsusb entries but does not seem to get picked up (for example) in iwconfig. Do I need to install *another* driver? The instructions seem to point to the same rtl8812au repo that the tplink requires. I can rerun that but I don't really understand why that would work or what state I should be re-installing from. Ideally I don't want to wipe the old driver that works with the TPLink to merely try to get this new one working.

Any ideas on debugging this particular case?

UPDATE:

I have installed the driver as per the answer below. It appears to be configured but can not yet get it running. Have tried rebooting and "sudo ip link set ... up/down" etc.

Now seeing

```
iwconfig

wlxa09f10b9ff56  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

UPDATE:

After a number of other steps and trying things (I think these were irrelevant but it is possible I have forgotten/omitted an important step) I notice that I now have a second entry in the wifi dropdown menu in the UI. Turning off the old device and ON the new device then lead to me being able to select a network.*I had to re-enter* my password for the network. I think this is the subtle point that is easy to not understand in the command line. There must be some key saving routine that is device-specific on ubuntu. Anyway, I now seem to have a connection through the new device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the driver from this [git repo](https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver):

```
sudo apt install build-essential dkms
git clone "https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver.git" /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git
sed -i 's/PACKAGE_VERSION="@PKGVER@"/PACKAGE_VERSION="git"/g' /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-git/dkms.conf
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v git
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

(and probably reboot).

Comment: Interesting. How would one know to do this? I was reading instructions that pointed to this one I think https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git

Comment: so this installed and appears to be configured but still not yet working. I have rebooted, I have also tried replugging in as well as "sudo ip link set ... up/down" etc. Will update the question above to reflect steps taken so far.